# Python : Converting string to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

From an API response, I am getting the following value for 'created_at' field:

```
 {'created_at': u'Mon Jul 08 12:00:16 +0000 2013'}
```

In order to convert '`Mon Jul 08 12:00:16 +0000 2013`' to python **`datetime`** object, I have tried different cases with '`datetime.strptime()`' but nothing found working.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried and the problems you encountered.

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com** & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a MCVE ( **a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code** ) showing what-you-have-tried so far. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & **to show your will** to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: Try https://labix.org/python-dateutil

Comment: for more inspiration, you may kindly try searching StackOverflow for already answered questions on the same or a similar subject. >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/22223725/3666197 **may help you get further to an MCVE**

Comment: related: [Python: parsing date with timezone from an email](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279)

Comment: Actually, this question is not exactly a duplicate! The ``+0000`` part is unique for this date string. Most importantly, simple ``%z`` which corresponds to that timezone format won't work for everyone because it only in ``Python 3.2+``.

Comment: @go2: have you tried it? [The answer works as is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435566/4279) (It works on both Python 2.7, and Python 3). I've linked above to [the answer that works on Python 2.6+](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279) if you need it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian My comment is referring to the duplicate displayed on top of the original question (e.g. Converting string...). Sorry, I didn't see you previous comment here (e.g. related Python: parsing....). Finally, I should indicate that my comment relates to the use of ``datetime.strptime()``.

Comment: @go2: yes, I'm talking about [**the answer to the duplicate question**. I don't see strptime() in it at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435566/4279). For an answer, look in the answers, not in the question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I never said that there was ``strptime()`` in it. What I mean, is that I started writing my initial comment before yours was posted. Hence, my comment is still valid as an advice if someone wants to use ``datetime.strptime()``.