# Compare date with current date in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, rfc2822

How do I compare a datetime object of this format

"Thu, 15 Jan 2015 06:35:37 GMT" with the current time ?

Comment: With [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: there are two questions: 1. how to [convert the string (`str` object) into `datetime` object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26435530/4279) 2. How to [compare it with the current date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime` module to convert from datetime string into datetimetime object.
then get different between two datetime objects.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime.strptime("Thu, 15 Jan 2015 06:35:37 GMT", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", )
>>> b = datetime.strptime("Fri, 16 Jan 2015 07:40:40 GMT", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", )
>>> c1 = b - a 
>>> c1
datetime.timedelta(1, 3903)
>>> c1.days
1
>>> c1.total_seconds()
90303.0
>>> c1.seconds
3903
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with the `dateutil` package. First install `dateutil` and then:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parsed_time = parse("Thu, 15 Jan 2015 06:35:37 GMT")
```

Then you can do `from datetime import datetime` and get the current time with `datetime.now()`, and you'll have two datetime objects you can compare however you like.

If you can't use `dateutil`, you can still do it with `datetime.strptime()`, but you'll have to specify the date string exactly which is quite fiddly. Refer to the standard library documentation in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz

# Convert the input date string to "seconds since the epoch" (POSIX time)
timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz("Thu, 15 Jan 2015 06:35:37 GMT"))
# Compare it with the current time (ignoring leap seconds)
elapsed_seconds = time.time() - timestamp
```