# Python convert date string to timestamp

Tags: python, python-2.7, date

I need to convert string type *Wed, 18 May 2016 11:21:35 GMT* to timestamp, in Python. I'm using:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(string, format)
```

But I don't want to specify the format for the date type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I don't want to specify the format for the date type.

Then, let the [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) parser figure that out:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("Wed, 18 May 2016 11:21:35 GMT")
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 18, 11, 21, 35, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse rfc 822 time string that is used in email, http, and other internet protocols, you could use `email` stdlib module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz

timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz("Wed, 18 May 2016 11:21:35 GMT"))
```

See [Converting string to datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26435530/4279).