# Python. Get file date and time (timestamp) from HTTP server

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp

I need to use a Python program to download a file from an HTTP server while preserving the original timestamp of the file creation.

Accordingly, two questions:

1. How to get file date from HTTP server using Python 3.7?
2. How to set this date for the downloaded file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) to download the file and get the modification date from the headers.

To set the dates you can use [os.utime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime) and [email.utils.parsedate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parsedate) for parsing the date from the headers (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472336) by tzot).

Here is an example:

```
import datetime
import os
import time
import requests
import email.utils as eut


url = 'http://www.hamsterdance.org/hamsterdance/index-Dateien/hamster.gif'
r = requests.get(url)
f = open('output', 'wb')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
last_modified = r.headers['last-modified']
modified = time.mktime(datetime.datetime(*eut.parsedate(last_modified)[:6]).timetuple())
now = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.today().timetuple())
os.utime('output', (now, modified))
```